# What does the force equation of kinetic molecular theory actually mean?

Tags: kinetic-theory, gas

Actually I was learning about kinetic molecular theory of gases. The equation of force exerted by molecules on the wall is

$$F=N\frac{mv^{2}_{x}}{L}$$

Where *N* is the *number of particles* and *L* is the *length of container*, $v_{x}$ is the *x dimensional velocity*. Now for a particle the equation is

$$F=\frac{mv^{2}_{x}}{L}$$

And this equation is analogous to the **Centripetal Force equation.**
$$F=\frac{mv^{2}}{r}$$

`Then from these equations we can say that the force exerted and felt by the molecules are equivalent to the Centripetal Force acting on them when they are spinning around a circle of radius equal to the distance between the walls of the container.`

Am I right?
What were the consequences of this?
Can anyone please explain the connection between these (if exist) or please correct my misinterpretation.

(Sorry if I have made  any mistake in this topic. I'm new to this topic. If there's any uncorrectable mistake please mention that either. Thanks!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *consequences*.

I would forget about the analogy, reasoning that just because the form of a pair of equations is the same there must be a "special relationship" between them.
It is certainly true that in both cases the end result is a change in the direction of the velocity with the magnitude of the velocity staying the same, but so what?

In some ways your reasoning is analogous to saying that because *work done (= force $\times$ distance)* and *torque  (= force $\times$ distance)* there is a "connection" between them.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.  But your analogy is really great. Thanks!!!